# Bootstrap carousel is not working if set it with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap carousel does not work in example below. It works when I copy it to `.content`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function Type_Button() {
      $("div#content").html('<div id="Doodle" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500"><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="item active" style="padding: 0;"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-loteria-2019-6753651837108772.2-2xa.gif"></div><div class="item" style="padding: 0;"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-halloween-2016-6753651837108773-2xa.gif"></div></div></div>');
      }
    window.onload = Type_Button;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's available. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/carousel/

Comment: Thanks @Tethys0 - it's listed [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/) rather than [where I was looking](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/) (the old Bootstrap docs were so oddly organized...).

Comment: Metha - My question remains, though -- why use such an outdated version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the carousel method manually as you're trying to inject the html code after body onload.

> Call carousel manually (at the end of Type_Button() function)  with:

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

You can try a bunch of options inside it - check -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#options

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function Type_Button() {
        $("div#content").html('<div id="Doodle" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500"><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="item active" style="padding: 0;"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-loteria-2019-6753651837108772.2-2xa.gif"></div><div class="item" style="padding: 0;"><img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-halloween-2016-6753651837108773-2xa.gif"></div></div></div>');

        $('.carousel').carousel();
      }
      window.onload = Type_Button;

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```